# How does python "for...in..." work when remove is used in loop body?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

In this Python snippet:

```
l = [10,20,30,40,50]
for i in l:
    l.remove(i)
    print(i)
print(l)
```

The output is:

```
10
30
50
[20, 40]
```

This behavior in Python takes me several hours to debug.
How does "for...in..." actually work?

Comment: I'm thinking that it uses an internal indexer, so when you start you're at index 0, then it jumps to 1 and so on, but since you're also deleting stuff from the array, l[1] was originally 20 but is now 30 so the end result is what you're getting. Just a speculation since I'm not a pro at python

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list

Comment: Did you do any research at all? Google anything?

Answer (score 2):

'i' in your code takes the value of each of the elements in your l list. So typing `for i in l` i will first become the first index, in this case 10, then perform the code underneath, which removes i from the list so now your list is `[20,30,40,50]` it prints i.. Which was 10. it then hops onto the next index, l[1] which is NOW 30 and performs the code.

Comment: Note that though it's true that CPython behaves like this, that behavior is afaik unspecified and should not be depended upon.

Comment: In the future, please flag duplicate questions for closure as such rather than answering them, as the latter increases fragmentation and makes the site harder to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

As @A. Lau has mentioned, in the second iteration of your `for` loop, `i` will be indexed as the second element of `l`, thus `l[1]=30` will be assigned to `i`.

If you really want to delete element in a for loop, you can try something like this:

```
l = [10,20,30,40,50]
for i in l[:]:
    l.remove(i)
    print(i)
print(l)
```

The result will be:

```
10
20
30
40
50
[]
```

Comment: In the future, please flag duplicate questions for closure as such rather than answering them, as the latter increases fragmentation and makes the site harder to navigate.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 got it, thanks for the information :-)